# Does VLC Media Player 2.2.4 support hardware acceleration on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: hardware, vlc

It is all in the question. I want to know if the latest stable version of VLC Media Player (2.2.4) supports hardware acceleration on a Raspberry Pi 3. The GPU is of course the VideoCore IV. When using VLC on Ubuntu MATE 16.04, the lag made the video unwatchable. Please do not suggest manually compiling VLC to support hardware acceleration: I am not tech-savvy enough to do this.

On another note, I have found Media Player Classic very good at playing Full HD content on low spec machines. Is there another media player that could do this on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: I use the video player that is installed with the OS, omxplayer, it works reliably on all versions of my Raspbis...

Comment: Unless the maintainers of Ubuntu MATE are willing to provide Raspberry Pi specific packages/repos this is never going to happen since the RPi acceleration is useless for 99 % of Ubuntu users who don't have a Pi

Comment: According to the modules list (`vlc --list | grep -E '(264|omx)'`) there's OMX support compiled into VLC 2.2.4. The `rules` file explicitly configures vlc with the necessary options for HW acceleration referenced in older posts. Though H.264 (and MPEG2 with purchased license key configured) video playback is laggy on my Pi3.